# Parallel Arrays, numeric Grades and letter grades

Tags: c++

So I created this little program that gives a letter grade based on the user input. Everything works well except when user enters number 90 or over, its not gonna display a correct letter:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int grade; // variable for user input

    int numberGrade[] = {90, 80, 70, 60, 0}; // initializing an array for numeric grades
    char letterGrade[] = {'A','B','C','D','F'}; // initializing an array for letter grades

    cout << "Enter the grade : ";
    cin >> grade;

    // for loop to output the correct letter based on the userInput
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(grade >= numberGrade[i] && grade < numberGrade[i-1])
            cout << "The grade is " << letterGrade[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I maybe modify my `if` statement so that when user enters number 90 or over the right result will displayed?

Comment: Question: what array index is being looked up when i == 0?  `&& grade < numberGrade[i-1]`

Comment: the easiest way would be to write another `if` statement before this one, which just checks `if(grade >=90) char letterGrade1 = 'A'; cout<<"The grade is " <<letterGrade1<<endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition inside the for loop is incorrect for the grade "A". That is because numberGrade[i-1] for i=0 would be i = -1. Hence, you do not get the answer for that!

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
int main() {
int grade; // variable for user input

int numberGrade[] = {90, 80, 70, 60, 0}; // initializing an array for numeric grades
char letterGrade[] = {'A','B','C','D','F'}; // initializing an array for letter grades

cout << "Enter the grade : ";
cin >> grade;
int flag = 0;
// for loop to output the correct letter based on the userInput
for(int i = 4; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if(grade >= numberGrade[i])
        continue;

    else
    {
        flag = 1;
        cout << "The grade is " << letterGrade[i+1] << endl;
        break;
    }

}
if(!flag)
    cout << "The grade is " << letterGrade[0] << endl;

return 0; }
```

I think it is pretty self explanatory, we just add a flag and check for the grade "A" condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sahil Shah. But is there any possibility to do that using only and only one if else statement?

Comment: You can, but not with the current logic. If try not to complicate things, this method seems okay.
You can definitely change your logic and implement it using one if - else condition.